# Can't get an implementation of Grails ObjectMarshaller<JSON> to work

Tags: json, grails

I'm trying to implement a custom marshaller in Grails. Here's the marshaller:

```
class AdultPlanningMarshaller implements ObjectMarshaller<JSON> {
    boolean supports(Object theObject)
    {
        return theObject instanceof AdultPlanning
    }

    void marshalObject(Object theObject, JSON theConverter)
    {
        AdultPlanning adult = (AdultPlanning)theObject

        JSONWriter writer = theConverter.getWriter()

        writer.object()

        writer.key('id').value(adult.id)
        ...    
        writer.endObject()
    }
}
```

I'm registering it in bootstrap.groovy and when I run my integration tests, the supports method fires correctly and the marshalObject method is called with the right object and a JSON object.

When I hit the:

```
writer.object()
```

call, an exception gets thrown:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONException: Misplaced object: expected mode of INIT, OBJECT or ARRAY but was DONE
```

So it looks like the writer has already done something to completion, but I have no clue what.

There's not a lot of documentation on JSON marshallers and examples are thin on the ground, but I think I've done this right but it sure isn't working.  Any hints would be appreciated.

Further work with the debugger seems to indicate that the object marshaller is being called twice, although breakpoints only happen on the 2nd call for some reason.  The first time through it seems to work just fine since the JSONWriter that I get via theConverter.getWriter() when the breakpoint DOES work has the JSON of the object correctly marshalled.  It's the 2nd call that is blowing up since the object has ALREADY been marshalled and the JSONWriter is no longer in the "init" state.  There's nothing obviously available to tell the difference between the two calls, but why it the marshaller being called twice?

As requested, here's the controller.  It's the show action that's being triggered:

```
class PrimaryController extends RestfulController  implements AlwaysRenderJsonException {

    def springSecurityService
    def familyService

    static responseFormats = ['json']

    PrimaryController() {
        /*
         * Tell the base class the name of the resource under management.
         */

        super(Primary)
    }

    @Override
    protected Primary createResource() {
        //def instance = super.createResource()
        //TODO: Should be able to run the above line but there is an issue GRAILS-10411 that prevents it.
        // Code from parent is below, as soon as the jira is fixed, remove the following lines:

        Primary instance = resource.newInstance()
        bindData instance, this.getObjectToBind()

        //Code from super ends here

        def family = familyService.safeGetFamily(params.long('familyId'))

        familyService.addAdultToFamily(instance, family)    // Add the primary member to the family.

        return instance
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a resource for the given id
     * @param id The id
     */

    @Override
    def delete() {
        if(handleReadOnly()) {
            return
        }

        Child instance = queryForResource(params.id)
        if (instance == null) {
            notFound()
            return
        }

        /*
         * Because of the multiple belongsTo relationships of events, you have to get rid of all
         * the events and make the profiles consistent BEFORE deleting the person instance.
         */

        instance.removePerson()

        request.withFormat {
            '*'{ render status: NO_CONTENT } // NO CONTENT STATUS CODE
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Primary> listAllResources(Map params) {
        if (params.familyId == null)
        {
            throw new ESPException("params.familyId may not be null")
        }

        def user = springSecurityService.loadCurrentUser()

        return \
            AdultPlanning.where {
                family.id == params.familyId \
                && family.user == user \
                && typeOfPerson == PeopleTypeEnum.PRIMARY
            }.list()
    }

    @Override
    protected Primary queryForResource(Serializable id) {
        def inst = familyService.safeGetAdult(Long.parseLong(id), params.long('familyId'))

        /*
         * It was safe to access the requested id, but the requested id may NOT be a primary
         * so we need to check.
         */

        return (inst instanceof Primary ? inst : null)
    }

    /**
     * Show the primary for the specified family.
     *
     * @return
     */

    @Override
    def show() {
        Primary primary = familyService.safeGetFamily(params.long('familyId'))?.primary

        respond primary
    }
}
```

And the Integration test that triggers it:

```
void "We should be able to show a primary."() {
    given:
    family.addToAdults(new Primary(firstName: "Barney"))
    family.save()
    family.adults.each { it.save() }

    when:
    controller.response.reset()
    resetParameters(controller.params, [familyId: family.id])
    controller.request.method = 'GET'
    controller.show()

    then:
    1 * mSpringSecurityService.loadCurrentUser() >> user
    controller.response.json
    controller.response.json.firstName == "Barney"
}
```

Comment: This should work, which grails version are you using? And can you post the the controller action code where you are responding the instances.

Answer (score 4):

Well, this is embarrassing.

I use IntelliJ as my Java/Groovy IDE.  I had a work related thing to do this morning and quit IntelliJ.  When I restarted IntelliJ, the problem described above that had been completely reproducible was no longer happening and the appropriate JSON was being produced under all circumstances.

So it appears that the IntelliJ state somehow got corrupted and the restart cleared it out.

Problem solved.

I guess.

Thanks for the help/suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

As OP mentioned, this error can be triggered because of IntelliJ :

`org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONException: Misplaced object: expected mode of INIT, OBJECT or ARRAY but was DONE`

Indeed, when debugging the marshaller (for example), IntelliJ displays the "toString()" of the variable, which causes the change of the mode from `INIT` to `DONE`.

You may want to remove your breakpoints when facing this issue ;)

Comment: This turned out to be my problem and I chose to revert back to my last commit and use a text editor (instead of IntelliJ) to make the desired changes.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason for this can be that where you have started `writer.object()` for some nested object or array response but missed to write `writer.endObject()` or you have wrote it two times.

So double check your custom marshaller for all write object.

Reference: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/65b42b66821b32d4efb3a229da99691a00575d60/grails-web-common/src/main/groovy/org/grails/web/json/JSONWriter.java#L258

Hope This helps!

Thanks,
SA

Comment: The custom marshaller is provided above functionally in it's entirety.  No missing endObject, no nested arrays.